# What is the format in date command to display the current date as "DATE: 27/11/17

Tags: date

I need a prefix `DATE:`. how can I display prefix along with the date.

```
date +%d/%m/%y
```

This displays only the date. I need a prefix string also.
Output should be `DATE: 27/11/17`

Comment: note that not using the ISO 8601 standard date format (YYYY-MM-DD) will give ambiguous dates that mean different things to different people.  e.g. is 11/12/17 the 11th of December (most of the world) or the 12th of November (Americans and a few others).   Interpretation mostly depends on whether you're American or not. or whether you've had your country "reconstructed" by the US so that American oddities become your normal.   You can avoid this ambiguity by using the ISO 8601 format.

Comment: Did you read the manual?

Comment: Please, for everything that's good in the world, don't use two-digit years. There's still more than ten years left during which the year numbers can get confused with the day of month.

Comment: @cas, YYYY-MM-DD also has that great property that `sort`, `sort -n`, `sort -g`, `sort -V` on them gives you the chronological order (for `-n` and `-g` because of the fall-back to lexical order for identical years)

Answer (score 3):

Any non-percent character is copied to the output, so

```
 date +'DATE: %d/%m/%y'
```

gives me

```
DATE: 04/10/19
```

Answer (score 0):

```
date "+DATE: %d/%m/%y"
```

gives the output as

```
DATE: 12/05/20
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please not that your approach is basically the same as that [suggested by Icarus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/545221/377345). You may want to edit your post to make clear where the difference lies.